# Loading an hierarchy of ApplicationContexts in WebApplicationInitializer

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, servlet-3.0

I'm using Servlet 3 (Tomcat 7) + Spring 3.1, and trying to load my webapp using WebApplicationInitializer.

In the usual examples I've seen, you have a Root ApplicationContext, loaded with ContextLoaderListener, and a servlet ApplicationContext, loaded with DispatcherServlet.

(To be clear, I'm not talking about web.xml, but programatically, inside WebApplicationInitializer).

Now, I'd like to have a hierarchy of ApplicationContexts, let's say:

Root -> AppContext1 -> AppContext2 -> ServletAppContext

**->** denotes Parent -> Child relationship. Each AppContext can access its own beans and the ones of its ancestors.

For an example:

- Root defines properties, DAO and TX.
- AppContext1 defines JPA and Spring Data repositories.
- AppContext2 defines JMS and Spring integration pipes.
- ServletAppContext defines Controllers and views.

My first approach was to add the Root ApplicationContext to the ContextLoaderListener, Then set it as a parent of AppContext1. Set AppContext1 as a parent of AppContext2. Set AppContext2 as a parent of ServletAppContext. And finally associate ServletAppContext with the DispatcherServlet.

The thing is, at shutdown time, DispatcherServlet closes ServletAppContext, but it does not propagate. AppContext1 and AppContext2 are never closed to their beans are never released. So I'm guessing I'm using a wrong approach.

I tried associating AppContext2 to ContextLoaderListener instead of Root. In this case, AppContext2 closes, but AppContext1 and Root remain open.

I also cannot have 3 ContextLoaderListeners, 1 for each of my AppContexts (Root, 1, 2).

My question is, what's the right approach for this situation? I'm open to suggestions.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why do you need such a complicated scheme in the first place.

Comment: The idea is to achieve better modularization of the beans (which I think should be a good practice).  I don't think it should be complicated, and of course you can't do this with web.xml, so this is a new approach. As a bonus, it minimizes the beans that are not eligible for post processing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, clearly I'm trying to do something Spring (at least up to version 3.1) is not prepared to do.

Answer (score 1):

The default behavior of not closing the parent context is because a single parent context could be shared by multiple child contexts.  In such a scenario the parent context can be closed only after all the child contexts are closed.

If it is a linear relation (i.e., there is only one child for each context) then you can use an extended ApplicationContext implementation whose close method calls the parent close as well.

If it is not a linear relation - then you can implement a reference counting mechanism to keep track of how many active child contexts are there, when it reaches 0 close the context.

Before doing any of this you should strongly reconsider the reason for having so many contexts.  It might be better to create only two contexts and use imports to connect the config files. I looks like over engineering to me. I can't think of a good use case of doing something like this, would be very interested in hearing why you are doing this.

Comment: See my comment above for an explanation